# Google Maps API + Internet Explorer + Markers Not Showing

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I can't seem to get the markers to show up for Internet Explorer, despite it working fine on other browsers.

When I run it on IE, it makes me debug it and gives the error. 
"Line: 173
Error: 'console' is undefined"

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
var markerList = new Array();
var propertyList = new Array();
var itemDisplayList = new Array();
var geocoder;
var map;
var latLng;
var browserSupportFlag =  new Boolean();
var yaml;

var currentWindow = null;
var addr = "Kansas, KA"

function initialize() {
   newMap();
   showAllProperties();
   <% @yaml = YAML.load(File.read("config/property.yml")) %>
   <%
    addr = []
    name = []
    link = []
    contact = []
    @yaml.each do |property|
      prop = Property.new(property)
      addr << prop.format_address
      contact << prop.format_contact_info
      name << prop.property
      link << prop.link
    end
   %>
   var addresses = <%= addr.to_json %>;
   var names = <%= name.to_json %>;
   var contacts = <%= contact.to_json %>;
   var links = <%= link.to_json %>;
   var i = 0;
   function slow_addMarker(){
   if(i < addresses.length){
     var propertyObj = {address: addresses[i], name: names[i], link: links[i], contact: contacts[i]};
     propertyList.push(propertyObj);
     addMarker(propertyObj, i);
     i++;
     if (i < addresses.length){
         timeout = setTimeout(slow_addMarker,500);
     }
    }    
   }
   slow_addMarker();
/*
   for(var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++)
   {
     var propertyObj = {address: addresses[i], name: names[i], link: links[i], contact: contacts[i]};
     propertyList.push(propertyObj);
     addMarker(propertyObj, i); //We need to specify the id or else items can be populated in the wrong order due to difference in API call timing
   }
*/
   itemDisplayList = $('.locations li');
}

function newMap()
{
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var myOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
      }; //end of my options
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  geocoder.geocode({'address': addr}, function(results, status)
  {
    if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
    {
      latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
      map.setCenter(latLng);
      // var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
      //   {
      //     // map: map,
      //     position: latLng
      //     // icon: "/images/common/gmap_blue_icon.png",
      //     // shadow: "/images/common/shadow50.png"
      //   });
      // google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()
      //        {
      //          if (currentWindow != null)
      //          {
      //            currentWindow.close();
      //          }
      //          infoWindowHere.open(map,marker);
      //          currentWindow = infoWindowHere;
      //        });
      }
    else
    {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0);
    }
  });

}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) 
{
  if(errorFlag == true)
  {
    alert("Geolocation service failed.");
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': "<%= Property.new(YAML.load(File.read("config/property.yml"))[0]).format_address%>"}, function(results, status) 
    {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        } 
      else 
        {
          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
  } 
  else 
  {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support geolocation.");
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': "<%= Property.new(YAML.load(File.read("config/property.yml"))[0]).format_address%>"}, function(results, status) 
    {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
      {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      } 
      else 
      {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
}

function addInfoWindow(propertyObject)
{
  var contentStr =''+
          '<div id="siteNotice">'+
          '<h2>'+ propertyObject.name +'</h2>'+
          '<p>'+ propertyObject.address +'</p>'+
          '<p>'+ propertyObject.contact +'</p>'+
          '<a class="goto" href="'+ propertyObject.link + '">View Details</a>'+
          '</div>';
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
    {
      map: map,
      content: contentStr
    });
  return infoWindow
}


function addMarker(propertyObject, id) 
{
  var wait_time = 200 * id;
  setTimeout(function(){
    geocoder.geocode({'address': propertyObject.address}, function(results, status)
    {
      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
      {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
          {
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
        markerList[id] = marker;
        // google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',  function()
        // {
        //   if (currentWindow != null)
        //   {
        //     currentWindow.close();
        //   }
        //   var infoWindow = addInfoWindow(propertyObject);
        //   infoWindow.open(map,marker);
        //   currentWindow = infoWindow;
        //   
        // });

      }
      else
      {
        //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        if (status = google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
          setTimeout(function(){addMarker(propertyObject, id)}, 600);  //try to reload it a bit later
        }
      }
    });
  }, wait_time);
}

function hideAllMarkers() 
{
  for( var i = 0; i < markerList.length; i++)
  {
    markerList[i].setVisible(false);
  }
}

function openWindow(map, marker)
{
  // // if currentWindow != null
  // //   google.maps.event.trigger(currentWindow, 'closeclick');
  // var infoWindow = addInfoWindow(propertyObject);
  // infoWindow.open(map,marker);
  // currentWindow = infoWindow;
}


function showAllProperties() 
{
  for(var i = 0; i < propertyList.length; i++)
  {
      markerList[i].setVisible(true);
      $(itemDisplayList[i]).show('slow');
  }
}

function showOneCity(city) 
{
  for(var i = 0; i < propertyList.length; i++)
  {
    if(propertyList[i].address.search(city) != -1)
    {
      markerList[i].setVisible(true);
      $(itemDisplayList[i]).show('slow');
    }
    else
    {
      markerList[i].setVisible(false);
      $(itemDisplayList[i]).hide('slow');
    }
  }
}

function showOneProperty(property)
{
  for(var i = 0; i < propertyList.length; i++)
  {
    // alert(propertyList[i].name + " " + property)
    if(propertyList[i].name == property)
      markerList[i].setVisible(true);
    else
      markerList[i].setVisible(false);

  }  
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no console in IE.  Remove or comment out line 173 (or write a console replacement function).  Once you do that it seems to work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much. For some reason the first time I tried this, I got even more errors in debugger, but once i turned the debugger off, it worked perfectly.